# Incidence matrix out of a boolean variable in R

Tags: r, boolean, adjacency-matrix

Probably a simple question. I have a dataframe of the different connections from different electrodes, all of them pairs of electrodes from two distinct brains

```
> head(inc)
  Null_Hyp Elec1 Elec2
1    TRUE   C3_1  C3_2
2    FALSE  C3_1  C4_2
3    FALSE  C3_1 CP1_2
4    TRUE   C3_1 CP2_2
5    FALSE  C3_1 CP5_2
6    FALSE  C3_1 CP6_2
```

I am trying to get an incidence matrix for all the pairs of electrodes, using the `Null_Hyp` information.

I am trying with `melt` from `reshape2` package but i cannot see how to introduce the argument of variable `Null_Hyp`.

At the end the beginning of the incidence matrix would look something like this:

```
       C3_1  C4_1  CP1_1  CP2_1  
C3_2    1      0      0      0
C4_2    0      0      0      0
CP1_2   0      0      0      0
CP2_2   1      0      0      0
```

Any ideas are welcome, I have been deep diving through the questions here but could not find any good answer.

Comment: Try `xtabs(Null_Hyp ~ ., inc)`.

Comment: It worked, I didn't know xtabs, thank you Rui!